# Calculate proportion of normal distribution above threshold

Tags: normal-distribution

Assuming I have a sample that follows a normal distribution with mean x and standard deviation y, how do I calculate what proportion of the sample is greater than threshold z?

Context:
I'm developing a dynamical systems model of homelessness in my community. In homeless services, people who have been homeless for a year or more are considered categorically different. I need an equation that estimates the number of people who have been homeless for a year or longer (threshold z) given changes in the average length of time homeless (mean x) and assuming a constant standard deviation (y).

Comment: Why would time homeless be normally distributed? I'd expect it to be pretty right skew.(and it can certainly never be negative)

Comment: Good point. I'm open to other distributions, but ultimately I'll need to make some simplifying assumptions for the model. Are there analytical solutions to this problem for, say, the negative binomial distribution? I'm bumping up against the limits of my knowledge...

Comment: 1. The negative binomial is discrete; if you were considering the normal, presumably your variable is continuous. $\,$ 2.  How are you dealing with the fact that such times are often censored?

Comment: Length of time homeless is technically continuous but is generally only measured in days (and the accuracy of the data is problematic, as you might expect). In the dynamical systems model, I need a way to approximate the number of people who cross the one-year threshold given an average length of time homeless (which will change based on other rates within the model) and I will have to make some simplifying assumptions about the variance.

Comment: I'd stick with continuous on times, even if it is discretized to days. Typical distributions used for durations/survival models would be where I'd start thinking (exponential, Weibull, gamma, lognormal etc etc)